# How to use Facebook graph API to retrieve fan photos uploaded to wall of fan page?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am creating an external photo gallery using PHP and the Facebook graph API.  It pulls thumbnails as well as the large image from albums on our Facebook Fan Page.

Everything works perfect, except I'm only able to retrieve photos that an ADMIN posts to our page.  (graph.facebook.com/myalbumid/photos)  Is there a way to use graph api to load publicy uploaded photos from fans?

I want to retrieve the pictures from the "Photos from" album, but trying to get the ID for the graph query is not like other albums... it looks like this: `http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=o.116860675007039`

Another note:  The only way i've come close to retreiving this data is by using the "feed" option.. ie:  `graph.facebook.com/pageid/feed`

**EDIT:**
This is about as far as I could get- it works, but has certain issues stated below.  Maybe someone could expand on this, or provide a better solution.  (Using FB PHP SDK)

```
<?php
require_once ('config.php');
// get all photos for album
$photos = $facebook->api("/YourID/tagged");
$maxitem =10;
$count = 0;
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo) {
    if ($photo['type'] == "photo"):
        echo "<img src='{$photo['picture']}' />", "<br />";
    endif;
    $count+= 1;
    if ($count >= "$maxitem") break;
}
?>
```

Issues with this:

1)  The fact that I don't know a method for graph querying specific "types" of Tags, I had to run a conditional statement to display photos.

2)  You cannot effectively use the "?limit=#" with this, because as I said the "tagged" query contains all types (photo, video, and status).  So if you are going for a photo gallery and wish to avoid running an entire query by using ?limit, you will lose images.

3)  The only content that shows up in the "tagged" query is from people that are not Admins of the page.  This isn't the end of the world, but I don't understand why Facebook wouldn't allow yourself to be shown in this data as long as you posted it "as yourself" and not as the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve **all** the albums and then get all the photos. This can be easily done by using FQL:

```
SELECT pid,owner,src_small,src_big 
FROM photo 
WHERE aid IN (
    SELECT aid 
    FROM album 
    WHERE owner = your_page_id
)
```

**EDIT:**
Also you need to query the stream table to get the wall posts then check if you have attachments and the type of the attachment:

```
SELECT attachment
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = 116860675007039
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "attachment": {
      "media": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1801693052786&set=o.116860675007039",
          "alt": "test",
          "type": "photo",
          "src": "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/185861_1801693052786_1553635161_1863491_4978966_s.jpg",
          "photo": {
            "aid": "6672812206410774346",
            "pid": "6672812206412558147",
            "fbid": 1801693052786,
            "owner": 1553635161,
            "index": 11,
            "width": 246,
            "height": 198
          }
        }
      ],
      "name": "",
      "caption": "",
      "description": "",
      "properties": [],
      "icon": "http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
      "fb_object_type": "photo",
      "fb_object_id": "6672812206412558147"
    }
  },
  {
    "attachment": {
      "description": ""
    }
  },
...etc
]
```

Comment: This only retrieves photos uploaded by page admin... i'm trying to retrieve photos Fans upload to our wall...

Comment: Getting closer, I believe I will have to target the stream.  I just need to figure out how to retrieve only photos from the query:  `SELECT attachment photo FROM stream WHERE source_id=116860675007039`
Currently this pulls all attachments (such as vidoes, etc).

Comment: @Joe: Yup just posted the same! :-)

Comment: I can almost smell it now.  ;)  Could you help with targeting only photos?  I was trying to use filter_key but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: This basically gets the same query:  http://graph.facebook.com/<insertpageID>/tagged

but i'm not sure how to force this to only pull photo posts (not videos)

Comment: @Joe: After getting the attachment the job of FQL is done. You need to loop over the result and filter the photo type.

Comment: is this only possible through FQL, not through the REST js graph api?

Answer (score 0):

try this FQL:

```
SELECT message,attachment,comments
FROM stream
WHERE source_id=YOUR_PAGE_ID AND filter_key="others" AND type=""
```

filter_key="others" - this will filter posts from everyone else, but not from Admin
type="" - this will filter out comments, so will leave you with photos (maybe videos and other strenge things, but removing text posts will reduce result massively)