# Facebook graph api call for a page's photos?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use facebook's graph api to retrieve a page's photos. Here's the call I'm using:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/'. $pageID .'/photos?access_token='. $page_access_token
```

For some reason this call returns an empty data set. I am using a page access token not an users, and the user is the admin of the page I'm trying to retrieve photos from. The page ID is correct since when I use this call to get the page's events it works well. Am I using the wrong call?

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)? try retrieving the photos of the page using your access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you're unfortunately stuck using FQL calls to get this type of information. Facebook has a lot of inconsistencies with how page data is handled -- I won't get into these, but what you're looking to do can be found here: [How to use Facebook graph API to retrieve fan photos uploaded to wall of fan page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083464/how-to-use-facebook-graph-api-to-retrieve-fan-photos-uploaded-to-wall-of-fan-pag)

Here's a PHP example:

```
    $photoQuery = urlencode('SELECT pid,owner,src_small,src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid  FROM album  WHERE owner = your_page_id)');    
    $photoFQL = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query='.$photoQuery .'&access_token='.$accessToken.'&format=json';   
    $photoResults = file_get_contents($photoFQL);
```

You'll end up with a url like this you can test with:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20pid%2Cowner%2Csrc_small%2Csrc_big%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20aid%20IN%20(%20SELECT%20aid%20%20FROM%20album%20%20WHERE%20owner%20%3D%{page_id})&access_token={access_token}&format=json

Replacing the {page_id} and {access_token} with your own, of course. I tested this and it showed my Community/Fan Page's photos in a JSON response. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's `3D{page_id})` and not `3D%{page_id})`. That is, no extra %.

Secondly, it seems to retrieve anything by photos uploaded by others.