# photos from Facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Facebook graph API to retrieve fan photos uploaded to wall of fan page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083464/how-to-use-facebook-graph-api-to-retrieve-fan-photos-uploaded-to-wall-of-fan-pag)

I spent all the day to understand how to get public photos from Facebook fan page.
I could not get it. I am using PHP (actually Yii framework).

This is my first time dealing with Facebook. I have found social plugins, I have read about Graph and other Facebook API, but I didn't get it.

I have a fan page (for example, https://facebook.com/Taviemmatiem), I need to get photos from Facebook and display them in another webpage.

1. Is it possible?
2. What technique should I use?
3. Is it possible without any authentication? (Fan page is public)

Please, give me some hints and keywords, afterwards I can Google myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Facebook graph API to retrieve fan photos uploaded to wall of fan page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083464/how-to-use-facebook-graph-api-to-retrieve-fan-photos-uploaded-to-wall-of-fan-pag) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446557/facebook-graph-api-call-for-a-pages-photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with [FQL Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and [FQL documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/).

Then look for some Facebook/FQL API for PHP.

Examplary query is:

```
SELECT aid, pid, src_big from photo where owner = me()
```